# Drawer display style

Tags: material-ui, drawer

I looked through the doc and couldn't find an attribute `z-index` which defines the `Drawer` display style : over / beneath the AppBar ? Any quick ways to do that ?
Thx,

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<Drawer
  containerStyle={{zIndex: 1000}}
>
```

for some `z-index` `!=` `AppBar`'s

Answer (score 0):

You can style the drawer and the app bar at the top-level of your app, using the `ThemeProvider`. There is a `zIndex` property which describes these values for different components.

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
  zIndex: {
    appBar: 1100,
    drawer: 1200
    }
  });

// Then, wrap your app with a ThemeProvider
<ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
  <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```